# Accelerator for polar molecules

Tags: science-based, nuclear-weapons

I'm writing a story where the protagonist(a scientist) invents an accelerator for polar molecules(Like H<sub>2</sub>O) using varying electric fields. In one of the experiments he accelerates the water molecules and collides them with each other. What can be the possible products of this collision?

(In my story the protagonist accidentally creates a very dangerous substance and tries to hide it from authorities etcetera. Are there any other possible ways I can use this device to do so(create something dangerous)?)

EDIT: The energies of the individual water molecules at the time of collision will be approximately 22.5 eV (my estimation)

Comment: Depending on speed, it'll be a spectrum between **Splash** -> **Steam** -> **Hydrogen / oxygen** (probably on fire) -> *insert CERN discoveries here*

Comment: 22eV is equivalent to about 250000K, which makes for a reasonably warm plasma but nothing excitingly nuclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 22.5 eV you won't be able to do anything worth weaponizing.

This is a [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy) of the nuclear binding energy per nucleus

[image]

As you can see the least energetic binding energy is anyway in the range of MeV.

Your energy is a million time smaller than that.

For additional comparison, 22.5 eV is the [energy of a photon](https://cleanroom.byu.edu/frequency-to-wavelength-to-energy-calculator) with wavelength 55 nm, which is an energetic UV photon and will strip quite some electrons from the atoms crossing its path, but will do nothing to the nuclei.

To give you an [historical perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron#History)

> At the Radiation Laboratory of the University of California, Berkeley, Lawrence and his collaborators constructed a series of cyclotrons which were the most powerful accelerators in the world at the time; a 69 cm (27 in) 4.8 MeV machine (1932), a 94 cm (37 in) 8 MeV machine (1937), and a 152 cm (60 in) 16 MeV machine (1939). He also developed a 467 cm (184 in), 730 MeV synchrocyclotron (1945). Lawrence received the 1939 Nobel Prize in Physics for the invention and development of the cyclotron and for results obtained with it.